# Finding and extracting immediate characters

Tags: linux, shell-script, text-processing, sql

I have a file with some SQLs and I want to find out the fields that have cast by using shell scripting.

For example, I have a file abc.txt with the below sql

> SELECT field1,field2,field3,field4,cast(field5 as
> integer),cast(substr(field6,5,10) as integer),(case when field7 = '0000/00/00' then cast(field7 as date) else (field8 as date) end) as field7, substr(field9,5,10) FROM TEMP;

Desired Output:

> field5
>
> field6
>
> field7

Comment: Quite the challenge, to parse semi-arbitrary SQL! (ref: the substr() call)

Answer (score 0):

How about the following:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="cast\\(";OFS="\n\n"}{ for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++) { sub("[ ),].*","",$i);gsub("^.*\\(","",$i) } {$1=""; print}}'
```

This solution iterates over instances of "cast(" on any line, then strips out prefixes and suffixes.

Answer (score 0):

To look for `field<decimals>` occurrences inside `cast(...)` statements, assuming there are no mismatched parenthesis, with GNU `grep` or compatible built with PCRE support:

```
<abc.txt grep -Po 'cast(\((?:[^()]++|(?1))*\))' |
  grep -Po '\bfield\d+\b'
```

That's using PCRE's ability to define *recursive* regular expressions. Above `(?1)` refers to the regular expression enclosed in `(...)`, so we're looking for `cast` followed by a regexp "R" that starts with `(` followed by any number of either non-parens (`++` is just the non-backtracking version of `+`) or more "R"s followed by `)`.

That allows us to find the matching `)` for the opening `(` that follows `cast`.

The second `grep` only extracts the `field<decimal>` (surrounded by *word boundaries* (`\b`)) from those `cast(...)` statements that the first `grep` extracts.

That assumes those SQL statements are on a single line. If not, you can add the `-z` option to the first `grep`.

Comment: Could you pls explain about the first command

Comment: @Balaji, see edit.